# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have this function that return a parsed_url structure that looks like this

```
typedef struct url_parser_url {
    char *protocol;
    char *host;
    int port;
    char *path;
    char *query_string;
    int host_exists;
} url_parser_url_t;

url_parser_url_t *parsed_url;
parsed_url = (url_parser_url_t *) malloc(sizeof(url_parser_url_t));
parse_url(address, true, parsed_url);
printf("parsed_url->path = %s\n", parsed_url->path);
```

The parse_url function looks like

```
int parse_url(char *url, bool verify_host, url_parser_url_t *parsed_url) {
    char *local_url = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(url) + 1));
    char *token;
    char *token_host;
    char *host_port;
    char *token_ptr;
    char *host_token_ptr;

    char *path = NULL;
    strcpy(local_url, url);

    token = strtok_r(local_url, ":", &token_ptr);
    parsed_url->protocol = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1);
    strcpy(parsed_url->protocol, token);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "/", &token_ptr);
    if (token) {
        host_port = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));
        strcpy(host_port, token);
    } else {
        host_port = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
        strcpy(host_port, "");
    }

    token_host = strtok_r(host_port, ":", &host_token_ptr);
    if (token_host) {
        parsed_url->host = (char *) malloc(
                sizeof(char) * strlen(token_host) + 1);
        strcpy(parsed_url->host, token_host);

        if (verify_host) {
            struct hostent *host;
            host = gethostbyname(parsed_url->host);
            if (host != NULL) {
                parsed_url->host_exists = 1;
            } else {
                parsed_url->host_exists = 0;
            }
        } else {
            parsed_url->host_exists = -1;
        }
    } else {
        parsed_url->host_exists = -1;
        parsed_url->host = NULL;
    }

    token_host = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &host_token_ptr);
    if (token_host)
        parsed_url->port = atoi(token_host);
    else
        parsed_url->port = 0;

    token_host = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &host_token_ptr);
    assert(token_host == NULL);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "?", &token_ptr);
    parsed_url->path = NULL;
    if (token) {
        path = (char *) realloc(path, sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 2));
        strcpy(path, "/");
        strcat(path, token);
        parsed_url->path = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(path) + 1);
        strncpy(parsed_url->path, path, strlen(path));
        free(path);
    } else {
        parsed_url->path = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
        strcpy(parsed_url->path, "/");
    }

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "?", &token_ptr);
    if (token) {
        parsed_url->query_string = (char *) malloc(
                sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));
        strncpy(parsed_url->query_string, token, strlen(token));
    } else {
        parsed_url->query_string = NULL;
    }

    token = strtok_r(NULL, "?", &token_ptr);
    assert(token == NULL);

    free(local_url);
    free(host_port);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I call the function parse_url and then I use the parsed_url->path member it throws me this segmentation fault

```
==16647== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

Can anyone to explain me what is happening and why ? Thank you

Comment: The error message is very clear. Get the debugger and find the location in the code.

Comment: That's no segmentation fault, though if you have one then it might explain why.  The message appears to be an excerpt from the output of valgrind.

Comment: If you compile with debug information enabled then valgrind should also give you details about where the error occurs in your code.  I recommend also turning off optimization to make such information as useful as possible.

Comment: I am suspicious of `host_port = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);`

Comment: @JohnBollinger   At this line it says the problem is:   **parsed_url->path = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(path) + 1); ** but I initialized the path with null earlier

Comment: If you initialized `path` as `NULL` (and it still has that value), then it is not an acceptable argument for `strlen()`.  `strlen()` requires a valid pointer to the first character of a string.  But it looks like `path` *does not* still have that value, so how you initialized it does not matter.

Comment: In any case, a [mcve] would include input with which you can reproduce the error, and should be trimmed back to the minimum (complete) code needed to reproduce it.

Comment: Aside: You are very likely on a system that provides the `strdup()` function.  If you are willing to rely on that (it is standardized by POSIX, but not directly by C), then it could make this code a lot simpler without changing its semantics.

Comment: Moreover, although I managed to reproduce your Valgrind message (but not a segfault), the problem disappeared after I converted your code to using `strdup()`.  That makes me pretty confident your problem is that you are ending up with an unterminated C string, probably as the result of passing too small a string length argument to `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And there it is.  Although it is supposed to be a safer alternative to `strcpy()`, the `strncpy()` has a nasty wart.  The standard says:

> The strncpy function copies not more than n characters (characters that follow a null character are not copied) from the array pointed to by s2 to the array pointed to by s1.

([C2011 7.24.2.4/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.4)), and note 308 clarifies that

> Thus, **if there is no null character in the first n characters of the array pointed to by s2, the result will not be null-terminated**.

The code that is ultimately responsible for your particular valgrind complaint is this:

```
    strncpy(parsed_url->path, path, strlen(path));
```

Since by definition there cannot be a null character within the first `strlen(path)` characters of `path`, that `strncpy()` reliably fails to ensure that the copy is null-terminated.  You have at least one other instance of the same problem in your code.

Since you seem to take sufficient care to ensure that enough space is available, one solution would be to switch from `strncpy()` to `strcpy()`.  That would also be more efficient, because you would avoid duplicate calls to `strlen()`.

As I noted in comments, however, if you're willing to rely on POSIX's `strdup()`, then that's cleaner than `strlen()` + `malloc()` + `str[n]cpy()`, and has the same semantics (you take responsibility for freeing the memory allocated for the copy).  You wouldn't have even had the opportunity to make these errors if you had made your copies that way.